# My modal just work fine for the first row of the table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

can anyone fix that for me really I spend a lot of time trying different solutions never works.

I use a tailwindcss template for the modal and javascript to show it or hide it.

I don't find the solution can anyone fix it, My modal just works fine for the first row of the table and did not work for the rest of rows

```html
 <!-- component -->
<div class="overflow-x-auto">
        <div class="min-w-screen min-h-screen flex items-start justify-center font-sans overflow-hidden">
            <div class="w-full lg:w-5/6">
                <div class="bg-white shadow-md rounded my-6">
                    <table class="min-w-max w-full table-auto">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="bg-gray-200 text-gray-600 uppercase text-sm leading-normal">
                                <th class="py-3 px-6 text-left">Event Title</th>
                                <th class="py-3 px-6 text-left">Description</th>
                                <th class="py-3 px-6 text-center">Date</th>
                                <th class="py-3 px-6 text-center">Image</th>
                                <th class="py-3 px-6 text-center">Status</th>
                                <th class="py-3 px-6 text-center">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="text-gray-600 text-sm font-light">
                        @foreach ($events as $event)

                            <tr class="border-b border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="py-3 px-6 text-left whitespace-nowrap">
                                    <div class="flex items-center">  
                                        <span class="font-medium">{{ $event->title }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="py-3 px-6 text-left">
                                    <div class="flex items-center">
                                        <span>{{ $event->description }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="py-3 px-6 text-center">
                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
                                    <span class="font-medium">{{ $event->date }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="py-3 px-6 text-center">
                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
                                        <img class="w-6 h-6 rounded-full border-gray-200 border -m-1 transform hover:scale-125" src="{{ Storage::url($event->image) }}" alt="{{ $event->place }}"/>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="py-3 px-6 text-center">
                                    @if(($event->status)==1)
                                    <span class="bg-purple-200 text-purple-600 py-1 px-3 rounded-full text-xs">Active</span>
                                    @else
                                    <span class="bg-red-200 text-red-600 py-1 px-3 rounded-full text-xs">Pending</span>
                                    @endif
                                    <!--<span class="bg-green-200 text-green-600 py-1 px-3 rounded-full text-xs">Completed</span>-->

                                </td>
                                <td class="py-3 px-6 text-center">
                                    <div class="flex item-center justify-center">
                                        <div class="w-4 mr-4 transform hover:text-red-700 hover:scale-110">
                                        <a href="{{ route('events.edit',$event->id) }}">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                             <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15.232 5.232l3.536 3.536m-2.036-5.036a2.5 2.5 0 113.536 3.536L6.5 21.036H3v-3.572L16.732 3.732z" />
                                            </svg>
                                        </a>
                                        </div>
   <!--------My delete buttton------------------>
                                        <div class="w-4 mr-2 transform hover:text-red-700 hover:scale-110">
                                       
                                         <a class="delete-btn" >
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5 4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16" />
                                            </svg>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                     
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
    
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {!! $events->links() !!}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  

       <!-- delet event confiming model-->
<div class="relative z-10 hidden" aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" id="overlay">
 
 <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" ></div>

 <div class="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
   <div class="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0">
  
     <div class="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-lg">
       <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
         <div class="sm:flex sm:items-start">
           <div class="mx-auto flex h-12 w-12 flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-red-100 sm:mx-0 sm:h-10 sm:w-10">
             <!-- Heroicon name: outline/exclamation-triangle -->
             <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-red-600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
               <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 10.5v3.75m-9.303 3.376C1.83 19.126 2.914 21 4.645 21h14.71c1.73 0 2.813-1.874 1.948-3.374L13.949 4.88c-.866-1.501-3.032-1.501-3.898 0L2.697 17.626zM12 17.25h.007v.008H12v-.008z" />
             </svg>
           </div>
           <form action="{{ route('events.destroy',$event->id) }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                     @method('DELETE')
                    <div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
                      <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900" id="modal-title">Delete an Event</h3>
                      <div class="mt-2">
                        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Are you sure you want to delete the event? All of the event data will be permanently removed. This action cannot be undone.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse sm:px-6">
              
                  <button type="submit" class="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-red-600 px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">Delete</button>
            
                 <button type="button" class="mt-3 inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm" id="close-modal">Cancel</button>
            </form>     
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>



       <!-- delet event confiming model script-->
<script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
            const overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay')
            const delBtn =  document.querySelector('.delete-btn')
            const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#close-modal')

            const toggleModal = () => {
                overlay.classList.toggle('hidden')
                overlay.classList.toggle('flex')
            }

            delBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleModal)

            closeBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleModal)
        })

        
      
    </script>
```

Comment: Because querySelector is just ONE element. You would need a loop

Comment: *`querySelectorAll()` and a loop

Comment: I rty to replace querySelector('.delete-btn') with querySelectorAll('.delete-btn') it dose not work for all rows even the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken directly from the MDN documentation:

> The [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) method [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) within
> the document that matches the specified selector, or group of
> selectors. If no matches are found, `null` is returned.

So regardless of the number of elements you have in your document with a class of `delete-btn`, using `document.querySelector('.delete-btn')` will only ever return the first element it finds.

As you want to be able to apply an event listener to **all** elements with the `delete-btn` class, what you really want is the [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method.

> The [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) method [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static (not live)
> [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) representing a list of the document's elements that match the
> specified group of selectors.

The `NodeList` returned from calling `document.querySelectorAll('.delete-btn');` is a collection (similar concept to an array) which contains all the elements located with the specified `selector`. As this is a collection and not a single element, you need to iterate over each of the collection elements and attach an `eventListener` to each iteration.

So applying the above to your use case, you might do:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.delete-btn').forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      toggleModal();
    })
  })
});
```

An [example CodePend](https://codepen.io/peppermintology/pen/VwxpxeM) for reference.

Comment: the modal appears in all rows but if I click on the delete button it deletes the first row in the table not the one I chose to delete! dose any one can help with this

Comment: @StudyingKSU You need to pass the `id` of the `event` to the modal so it knows which one to delete. My [example](https://codepen.io/peppermintology/pen/VwxpxeM) shows how you can do this using the `data` attribute.

Comment: can you calrify it in my situation ? becuse i already pass the id in the delete form

Comment: @StudyingKSU I have updated the CodePen example to show how you might set the correct `action` for the selected `event ID`.

Comment: thank you a lot you really help me :) , I'll clarify one thing since may someone face the same thing          document.getElementById('deleteform').setAttribute('action', `events/${eventId}`);
the action att should like this since I use resource controller.

Comment: @StudyingKSU Glad I could help. I have updated my CodePen example and changed the `route` as per your comment.